# Standards of dress for a classical concert in the Czech Republic

Tags: czech-republic, dress-codes

I'm going to be on a business trip in Prague later this month and am thinking of taking an evening to attend a performance of the Czech Philharmonic at the Rudolfinum. What are the local standards for appropriate dress for such an occasion?

Comment: Anything on this list except black/white tie (unless explicitly stated when you purchase the tickets) should be suitable https://www.artinstitutes.edu/about/blog/defining-dress-codes-what-to-wear-for-every-occasion

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As a local, if I was going to the Rudolfinum for Czech Philharmonic, I'd wear a dark suit and a tie. However, I would consider smart pants and a dress/formal shirt perfectly acceptable too.

I wouldn't recommend jeans or polo shirts.